# Bitcoin Core forgot Passphrase

Tags: bitcoin-core

I opened my bitcoin core wallet for the first time in nearly 7 years and do not remember ever setting a passphrase. The good news is I've got bitcoins in the account that I'd forgotten about, bad news is that without the passphrase, I can't send them anywhere to cash them out.

Is there a way to access / hack the passphrase for Bitcoin Core?

Comment: The first version of Bitcoin with wallet encryption support was released in september 2011, so it can't be more than 6 years.

Answer (score 0):

So you have bitcoin-cli installed on your local computer? Does the command *bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey "address"* of an address you know related to the wallet lead to the private key you need?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your questions - not great with technical things. I have Bitcoin Core installed on my mac and had bitcoins received there in 2011. Between then and now i have forgotten the passphrase and am locked out of sending my bitcoins to an exchange until I can remember or bypass the passphrase.

Comment: OK, you have installed it on your mac. Now you can try to find and execute the above command related to an address you have used in the past.

Comment: ok so run the command through terminal? And what address, the one of my current wallet? when I do that is says command not found

Comment: Yes, first try to find the command and run it. The address should be one which you have used in the past.

Comment: ok I tried bitcoin-clidumpprivkey"my address" and it came back with command not found

Comment: After ....cli is a blank. Look at the command above.

Comment: Try this to dump all keys from the wallet: bitcoin-cli dumpwallet "test" . This will put all info into the file test.